# Create Scrollable Div for Angular Chat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am creating a chat application in Angular and I am trying to set up the UI for it. I need to create a div that will be housing the chat messages and as more messages fill the div I do not want the div to expand but just stay the same size and show a scroll bar. This div should be 100% the size of the parent div. As you click the button to add data the div grows. Even if I set a height in px or percent format the div still grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link won't load but here are the basics to make a scrollable element:

**HTML / JS Structure**

1. Make an outer container `div`
2. Make an inner container `div` (this will be the "scroll wrapper")
3. Append the inner container to the outer container
4. Insert whatever you need into the inner container (you can use something like `insertAdjacentHtml` or whatever works for your specific situation)

This order of steps in particular will work well for a scenario where the contents are dynamically changing.

**CSS**

1. For the outer container

   - Set a fixed value for `width` and set `height: auto`
   - Set a `border-radius` if you want circular edges
   - Set `overflow: hidden` to keep the scroll wrapper's corners from popping out
   - You will probably want some `padding`
2. For the inner container

   - Set `position: relative`
   - Set `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: hidden` so that you can scroll up and down, but not side to side
   - For the desired overflow behavior, you need to set `width: 100%` and set fixed values for `max-height` and `min-height`. (`max-height` decides when things will start to overflow ie. make a scroll bar)

     - You will want `max-height` and `min-height` to be less than the outer container's fixed `width` + any `padding`, etc. it may have.